# how to identify which VM instances are using v0.1 and v1beta1 endpoints for app engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I have got an mail saying  **Legacy GAE and GCF Metadata Server endpoints will be turned down on April 30, 2020**.
I need to update my metadata server endpoints to v1. But how do I know the current versions of my metadata server endpoints.
I have checked the google cloud documentation of migrating to v1 metadata server. It has given two commands but I really don't know what it meant and where it has to be run.

I had an eye on the documentation and tried these two commands

```
    curl -H "Metadata-Flavor: Google" http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/legacy-endpoint-access/0.1
    curl -H "Metadata-Flavor: Google" http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/legacy-endpoint-access/v1beta1
```

but ended up with an error saying

**curl: (6) Could not resolve host: metadata.google.internal**

When I put my local host I am getting the output as

```
    <html>
    <head><title>404 Not Found</title></head>
    <body bgcolor="white">
    <center><h1>404 Not Found</h1></center>
    <hr><center>nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)</center>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Don't know how to proceed further.

Please help me.
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a thorough reading of [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/migrating-to-v1-metadata-server), I have understood that my metadata server endpoints will be automatically updated to v1 by the gcloud.

The only thing that we supposed to do is to  find the **processes**, **applications**, or **images** that are using the deprecated metadata server endpoints and update the dependencies(related to gcloud) to the latest version.
That's it! It is successfully updated to v1 metadata server.

Comment: do you know how to test if we've successfully updated those dependencies? I think I have, but I keep getting the email from GCP saying I'm using the old endpoints.

Answer (score 0):

Searching around about it, as per the documentation [Storing and retrieving instance metadata](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/storing-retrieving-metadata) the v0 Metadata version is deprecated and it's recommended to be moved to v1.

I would recommend you to access the documentation [Migrating to v1 metadata server endpoint](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/migrating-to-v1-metadata-server), that will provide more information to you on how to migrate to the version v1 Metadata.

Let me know if the information helped you!

Comment: This is the first time I am working on google cloud. I have read those documentations and tried some. Even though I am getting the error.

Comment: Hi @Himabindu could you please confirm which one of them have you tried and it did not work?

Comment: I have tried the above two commands(curl) by following the documentation.But I am getting an error like this ``curl: (6) Could not resolve host: metadata.google.internal``